# JQL to Identify Time Logged by Individual

Tags: jira, jql

Good morning! I've come across a few answers but maybe there's an update. Is there a way to query the time logged by a specific user in Jira? I've tried

```
  worklogauthor() = {user}
```

but the resulting Time Spent field brings back all the time logged, not just the time logged by the specific user entered.

Any ideas? I know there are add-ons with this information but if there's a way to get the same information through JQL and a dashboard gadget, that would be the preference - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try following JQL

```
issuefunction in workLogged("by username")
```

It can be filtered additionally by adding **after** date:

```
issuefunction in workLogged("by username after 2021/12/01")
```

or even narrowing it to specific period (**before** date)

```
issuefunction in workLogged("by username after 2021/12/01 before 2022/01/01")
```

Comment: I've got ScriptRunner Enhanced Search but I'm getting this error "Function - 'workLogged' does not exist"